# Is there any API available for fetching quip thread history?

Tags: quip

Is there any API available for fetching quip thread history like below:
[http://api.quip.com/thread/{thread_id}/history](http://api.quip.com/thread/%7Bthread_id%7D/history)? date=<required_date>

[image: Document History]